Were European algebraists aware of the work of Al-Khwarizmi?
Were European algebraists, such as  Cardano, del Ferro, Tartaglia, Viete, and Fermat, aware of the work of Al-Khwarizmi?
If yes, what impact did it have?
If not: Where did they learn to solve the quadratic equation?

Just out of curiosity, after seeing your previous question, are you trying to prove something about Al-Kharizmi?

@Mauricio I'm trying to understand better his role.  I'm specifically interested in the principal of homogeneity, which Viete expresses, Descartes rejects, and, as far as I can tell, was not adopted by Al-Khwarizmi.

YES. The most significant mathematical innovations of the high Middle Ages
were the introduction of algebra into Western Europe through the
translations of al-Khwarizmi's al-jabr (Liber algebre et almuchabala) and the foundation of abacist arithmetic in the Liber abaci by Leonardo da Pisa. It has been translated ito Latin by Robert of Chester in 1145 and by Gerard of Cremona.

People like del Ferro, Cardano, Tartaglia, Viète, and Fermat are from the 16-17th century. Al-Khwarizmi is from the 9th century. People like Fibonacci (13th century) had already translated what they could from Arabic sources into Europe. For example, Roger Bacon (13th century) promoted the use of Al-Khwarizmi's techniques as a necessary tool "to abound in the power of numbering"(*). So Al-Khwarizmi's algebra and numerals were almost ancient knowledge for the European mathematicians whom you cited.
(*) A Short Account of the History of Mathematics by W. W. Rouse Ball

Does the fact that it was old imply that it was well known and impactful?

We have famous European scientists like Fibonacci and Bacon promoting Al-Kharizmi's techniques. We have the adoption of Al-Kharizmi numerals and arithmetic all over Europe. And also words "algorism", "algebra", and "algorithm", being used all over, the work was clearly impactful.
